# warning de Java: uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, netbeans

Cuando quiero crear la carpeta `/dist` y que contenga dentro las librerias en `/lib`, además del `.jar` con el cual quiero trabajar más adelante para crear un `.exe`, entonces me encuentro con una serie de **warnings** al hacer "**Clean and build**" en un programa de **Netbeans**.

**PD:** He probado a eliminar la carpeta /dist una vez generada, para ver si el **warning** sólo ocurría si la carpeta /dist ya existía previmente pero nada.

```
Created dir: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 17 source files to C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build\classes
Note: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\src\interfaz\Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 11 files to C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\dist\agenda.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\dist\agenda.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

**Warning:**

```
Note: C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\src\interfaz\Login.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Deduzco que sean **warning** y no errores porque el programa me compila y funciona correctamente. Ejecuto el `.jar` y funciona, ¿pero por qué me genera ese código de advertencia? ¿Cómo puedo eliminar esas advertencias?

Estoy utilizando JDK1.8 con Netbeans 8.0.2 en Windows 8.1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Algunos de mis warnings** después de hacer: abrir el archivo **nbproject/project.properties**, buscar la clave **javac.compilerargs** y definir su valor como: `-Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked.`

```
C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\src\interfaz\Listado_clientes.java:88: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to TableRowSorter(M) as a member of the raw type TableRowSorter
            TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(modelo);
  where M is a type-variable:
    M extends TableModel declared in class TableRowSorter
C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\src\interfaz\Listado_clientes.java:89: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method setRowSorter in class JTable is applied to given types
            tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(sorter);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found: TableRowSorter
C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\src\interfaz\Listado_clientes.java:89: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            tabla_clientes.setRowSorter(sorter);
  required: RowSorter<? extends TableModel>
  found:    TableRowSorter
C:\Users\Osmar\Desktop\Agenda\agenda\src\interfaz\Listado_clientes.java:461: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = Conexiones.listado_clientes();
  required: ArrayList<Cliente>
  found:    ArrayList
```

Comment: Te recomienod hacer una pregunta por cada warning, acá te enseñamos como corregir los problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien indica la salida del **Clean and Build** que compartes, lo que ocurre es que estás usando APIs marcadas como ***deprecated*** además de tener en tú código warnings de tipo **unchecked**.

Para que el compilador te muestre exactamente donde están estos "problemas" debes pasarle los dos parámetros que te indica la salida. Para hacerlo abre el archivo *nbproject/project.properties*, busca la clave **javac.compilerargs** y define su valor como: *-Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked*.

Con lo anterior podrás saber donde están los "problemas" y solucionarlos.

**Paso 1**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Paso 2**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo acabo de realizar y he encontrado algunos errores, bastantes warning. Edito la pregunta para qué se puedan ver.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ves en la salida es una advertencia que te indica que estás usando un API que en algún tiempo tenía una forma de hacer, pero que la experiencia ha demostrado que ya no es la mejor práctica para este momento, a esto de le llama comunmente **deprecado** u **obsoleto**.

Asumiré que dicho API es Swing, rey indiscutible de las interfaces gráficas de escritorio en Java, pero que recientemente dejó de tener soporte (es decir actualizaciones gratis).

Lo más probable viendo que tu clase es un login es que estés usando un `JPasswordField` y que estés tratando de establecer y obtener la contraseña mediante un `String`.

Esto es una mala práctica, o cuanod menos una práctica insegura, ya que como sabes las cadenas son inmutables y viven en la memoria esperando ser reutilizadas.

Esto implica que cualquier persona con una herramienta simple como [cheat-engine](/questions/tagged/cheat-engine), podría pescar el usuario y contraseña que dejó un usuario previo de un memory dump, es por esto que ahora `JPasswordField` usa un arreglo de carateres que no prevalece en memoria además de pensar en que se puede cifrar más fácil.

La forma más obvia y que no entiendo por qué no te la mencionaron es cambiar a un método que no esté deprecado o hacer las cosas de otra forma. Tu mismo IDE puedes configurarlo para que en su linter te marque de otro color cuando un método esté deprecado y si no sabes como modernizarlo, este es el sitio perfecto para preguntar (stackoverflow).

Sin ver tu código no podríamos ayudarte más.

Comment: Uno de mis problemas son las conversiones de tipos de datos, aunque funcione, y también -como bien dices el campo jPasswordField-:  warning: [deprecation] getText() in JPasswordField has been deprecated
        String password = text_password.getText();
warning: [deprecation] getText() in JPasswordField has been deprecated
        } else if (text_password.getText().trim().isEmpty()){